# How can I get the current page number in GridMvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing MVC application in which I have used GridMvc, 
Now I am trying to use skip and take on index view. But here I want to get the current page number in the view, which means I would need to pass it from the view (where pagination is handled) to the controller (where I need it). But how can I get the page number in the controller, or how can I pass a variable back up the chain?

Here is the code for my index view, where the pagination is handled

```
@model IEnumerable<Epay.ViewModel.PurchaseOrderVM>
@using GridMvc.Html

   @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
   {
       columns.Add(c => c.PoNo).Titled("PO No").SetWidth(200);
       columns.Add(c => c.PoDate).Format("{0:dd-MMM-yy}").Titled("PO Date").SetWidth(150);
       columns.Add(c => c.CompanyName).Titled("Company").SetWidth(500);     
   }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)
```

And here is the code for the controller, where I am trying to get the page number

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
     PurchaseOrderService POService = new PurchaseOrderService();
     var POList = POService.GetAll();
      return View(POList); 
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've tried to make it more clear what you are looking for and reworded the question along the way.

Answer (score 0):

As per the source code, you should be able to get the current page number using the query string parameter "`grid-page`". But this parameter can be modified while constructing the grid. You can check the implementation for the property "`CurrentPage`". Link for the source code is below.

http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GridMvc/GridMvc/Pagination/GridPager.cs

If you return an IEnumerable or IQueryable as the model then GridMVC should do the paging for you. You do not have to manually do it.

Comment: Link is invalid.